# C++ Need help on Remove Node function

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have stressed my head out the last few days to figure out how to get this remove() function to work. I'm still a student and data structure is no joke.
I really need help on how to get this function to remove a specific number on the list from user input. Doesn't matter what I try, it still could not work right.

For example, the list is: [1, 2, 3]
I want to delete number 2 on the list. I want the remove() function to traverse thur the list, if it found number 2, then delete number 2.

```
    class SortedNumberList {
public:
   Node* head;
   Node* tail;

   SortedNumberList() {
      head = nullptr;
      tail = nullptr;
   }

   void Insert(double number) {
       Node* newNode = new Node(number);
       if (head == nullptr) {
           head = newNode;
           tail = newNode;
       }
       else {
           tail->SetNext(newNode);
           tail = newNode;
           
       }
   }

   // Removes the node with the specified number value from the list. Returns
   // true if the node is found and removed, false otherwise.
   bool Remove(double number) {
       Node* temp = head;     
       if (temp == nullptr) {
           return false;
       }
       if (head->GetData() == number) {
           head = head->GetNext();
           return true;
       }
       else{
           while (temp != nullptr) {
           Node* curNode = temp;
           Node* preNode = nullptr;
           preNode = curNode->GetPrevious();
           temp = temp->GetNext();
               if (curNode->GetData() == number) {
                   preNode = curNode->GetNext();
                   return true;
               }
               delete curNode;
           }
       }
       delete temp;
   }
};

class Node {
protected:
   double data;
   Node* next;
   Node* previous;

public:
   Node(double initialData) {
      data = initialData;
      next = nullptr;
      previous = nullptr;
   }

   Node(double initialData, Node* nextNode, Node* previousNode) {
      data = initialData;
      next = nextNode;
      previous = previousNode;
   }
```

Edit: I'm able to solve my own issue, thank you everyone.

```
bool Remove(double number) {
       // Your code here (remove placeholder line below)
       Node* temp = head;  //Make a temporary node point to head.
       
       if (temp == nullptr || head == nullptr) {  //if user don't provide input, return false.
           return false;
       }
       if (head->GetData() == number) {  //If number need to delete is at head.
           head = head->GetNext();
           return true;
       }
       else {
           while (temp != nullptr) {  //Travese temp node throught out a list.
               Node* curNode = temp->GetNext();  //Make a current node point at temp next.
               Node* preNode = temp;
               Node* sucNode = curNode->GetNext();
               if(curNode->GetData() == number) {  //Delete a node if number is found on the list
                   if (curNode->GetNext() == nullptr) {  //Delete at tail.
                       preNode->SetNext(nullptr);
                       tail = preNode;
                       delete curNode;
                       return true;
                   }
                   if (curNode->GetNext() != nullptr) {
                       preNode->SetNext(sucNode);
                       sucNode->SetPrevious(preNode);
                       delete curNode;
                       return true;
                   }
               }
               temp = temp->GetNext();
           }
       }
       return false;
   }
};
```

Comment: You really should draw a picture with boxes for the nodes and lines for the links, to illustrate what is done when you remove a node from a doubly-linked list.  If the current node data is equal to the number, you want to set the previous nodes `next` to the current node `next`, and set the next node's `prev` to the current node `prev`.  That unlinks the deleted node from the chain, and sets the links properly when that link is deleted.  Did you do that (i.e. draw on paper what is done?)

Comment: You might want to read [ask]. It is advisable to start your question with your question. Starting with excuses for not knowing the answer is a waste of everyone's time (that includes yours).

Comment: Look at the statement `delete curNode;` Can you spell out the condition when it is executed? 
How many times? Do you want it more than once? You also have `delete temp;` When is *that* executed? Do you want both of those executed?

Answer (score 0):

You should make Node a friend class of SortedNumberList or define former inside the later class which simplifies the code somewhat. It's personal preference but it leads to less unnecessary boilerplate code (getters and setters).

In a double linked list you do not need to keep track of the last as you do need on single linked lists because you have both pointers available.

The quest is just a matter of iterating to find the value, taking care to cut it early when we pass the mark since it is a sorted list.

Then delete the object and update the link pointers.

```
   bool Remove(double number) {
       // Loop through the entire list
       Node* temp = head;     
       while ( temp != nullptr) { 

           // There is no point looking forward if the list is sorted
           if (temp->data > number ) return false;

           // Compare to find
           if (temp->data == number) {

               // Get the pointers so we can delete the object
               Node* prev = temp->previous;
               Node* next = temp->next;

               // Delete object
               delete temp;

               // Update previous pointers
               if ( prev==nullptr ) {
                   head = next;
               } else {
                   prev->next = next;
               }

               // Update next pointers
               if ( next==nullptr ) {
                   tail = prev;
               } else {
                   next->previous = prev;
               }   

               // Indicate success
               return true;
           }
       }

       // We iterated to the end and did not find it
       return false;
   }
```